# Angular not updating page after http request (scope issue?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

When my page loads, all the items in my mongo db are displayed. I have a form to input new entries, or delete entries. When creating or deleting, the http process works, but the new data is not updated in the DOM.

Most of the related questions I have researched suggest to make sure my ng-controller wraps the entire body, which it does. Other's suggest to use $apply, but I've also read that this is wrong. When I try it, I am alerted "in progress" anyway.

My only guess is that after the http request, a new scope is loaded and angular doesn't pick up on that. Or for some reason its just not reloading the data after my request. Here is my code, thanks for your help.

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <!-- list records and delete checkbox -->
    <div id="record-list" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <!-- loop over records in $scope.records -->
            <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="record in records">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteRecord(record._id)">
                    {{ record.artist}} - {{ record.album }} - {{ record.bpm}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- record form data -->
    <div id="record-form" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="artist" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="Artist" ng-model="formData.artist">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="album" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="Album" ng-model="formData.album">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="bpm" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="BPM" ng-model="formData.bpm">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createRecord()">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.sortType     = 'artist';
$scope.sortReverse  = false;
//$scope.searchRecords   = '';
$http.get('/api/records/')
  .success(function(data) {
      $scope.records = data;
      console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function(data) {
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });
  $scope.createRecord = function() {
      $http.post('/api/records/', $scope.formData)
          .success(function(data) {
              //$scope.formData = {};
              $scope.records = data;
              console.log(data);
          })
          .error(function(data) {
              console.log('Error: ' + data);
          });
  };
  $scope.deleteRecord = function(id) {
      $http.delete('/api/records/' + id)
          .success(function(data) {
              $scope.records = data;
              console.log("delete record scope: " + data);
          })
          .error(function(data) {
              console.log('Error: ' + data);
          });
  };
```

}])

Comment: So does each HTTP operation (POST, DELETE) respond with the updated array of records? Also, the `success` and `error` callbacks on the `$http` promise have been [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice). Have you checked your console for any errors?

Comment: Check the response headers in your request. If you're able to log the response but it isn't showing up in your view, then chances are you're receiving Content-Type: text/plain when you should be receiving Content-Type: application/json. If that's the case you can change the response header in your server or if you're lazy you can just do $scope.records =  JSON.parse(data);

Comment: @Phil, that was my problem. My createRecord function wasn't returning the updated array of records. Also, thank you for informing me about the deprecation of `success` and `error` I've changed the code to use `.then(function successCallback(response)`. Thanks to all other for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller JS looks fine - I would say from looking at this that you need to export the updated values from your mongoDB collection when the POST/DELETE is successful.

If you use Mongoose (mongoDB plugin), you can update your API code to send back the updated data upon success with something like this:

```
// POST
// --------------------------------------------------------
// Provides method for saving new record to the db, then send back list of all records

app.post('/api/records', (req, res) => {

    // Creates a new record based on the Mongoose Schema
    const newRecord= new Record(req.body);

    // New record is saved to the db
    newRecord.save((err) => {

        // Test for errors
        if(err) res.send(err);

        // Now grab ALL data on records 
        const all = Records.find({});
        all.exec((err, records) => {

           // Test for errors
           if(err)  res.send(err);

           // If no errors are found, it responds with JSON for all records
           res.json(records);
        });

    });
});
```